# Light distro for eeepc

Tags: usb, eeepc

Hello i have an eeepc 900
I want to install a light distro on 4gb sd card for simple tasks
user must be able to launch mo3(through vlc), occasionally surf internet, and attach usb stick to get mp3 from
everything should be easy, form desktop, usb automount, click on drive launch mp3, and may be save them on desktop
no much
trying to test several distro but can't get out of it with a simple and easy distro
tried ubuntu mini, but after install packaing and desktop manager system seems not much usable, usb doesn't Mount, and other weird thing.
I am not experienced, and i should need somenthing ready to use
plaese an nelp for it
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this one [Lubuntu.](http://www.lubuntu.net/)

Lubuntu is the lightest Ubuntu flavor and a full desktop ready to use.

Comment: hello .i know lubuntu and i use it on another eeepc. but it seeems i cannot install on 4gb drive –